# Pasting from column B into column D

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy/paste item codes from column B into column D.

Most of the cells in column B are like this:

> XX787 DO BOLOGNESE 2X2.28KG FR

The item code is the first 5 characters in this case.

A few cells in column B are like this:

> 01333379 Rice Long Grain PB Milled 10  BB

In this case, the item code is 8 characters and consists of numbers + the first character is a zero.

The issues:

- The zero at the begin is not displayed when I copy/paste from column B into column D. I tried pasting all the cell values as text so that the zero would be displayed, but it didn't help.
  I used this code to format as text: `ActiveSheet.Range("B:D").NumberFormat = "@"`
- The first characters are put in column B, but when it more characters, the rest of the characters does not get put in.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine for me and is not deleting leading zeros:

```
Dim i As Integer

'Set the numberformat of column D to text
Range("D1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"

'Loop through the used rows
For i = 1 To UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row Step 1

    'assign the item code to column D
    Cells(i, "D").Value = Split(Cells(i, "B").Value, " ")(0)
Next i
```

To Explain the `Split()` function:
`Split()` splits the specified String (`Cells(i, "B").Value` in this case) into an array, you can specify the delimiter (which in this case is a space (`" "`)).

Since the returnvalue is an array, we can tell VBA to only return the first value, which should be the item code. This is done by adding `(0)` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target cells format to text before running the macro. If you do it after running the macro the zero won't be there.